# Birt cascading parameter with search box instead of combo box

Tags: java, eclipse, report, reporting, birt

I am new to BIRT reporting. I have following requirement

I want to load list of customer in BIRT parameter selection window. I have more than 3000++ customers to load. Hence our team came to a conclusion , to give a searchable text box in parameter window and once user type few character of customer name and press search button/hit enter, Then it will load the filtered set of customer matching with the name as a cascading drop down below the search box.

1. How I can do this in BIRT report?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use cascading parameters with a filter by some group... location, first letter in their name. See an example here - http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/examples/reports/2.1/cascade/cascade.rptdesign